# Query to get yesterdays data only for a specific time interval

Tags: sql-server, reporting

Here is my where condition which I use for daily data but I've got to change the date
everyday.

```
WHERE X.stage = 'Approval'
AND
X.T_ExitTime between '2015-08-06 06:00:00:000' and  '2015-08-06 17:00:00:000'
ORDER BY x.T_ExitTime asc
```

How can we make this to use the timeframe 0600-1700 for yesterday or for the same day without having to change it manually everyday and so that we can make this a Job and automate it

**I'm using SQL Server 2008**

Comment: Why don't you make an automatic job? Cronjob?

Comment: @oNare Creating the job isn't the problem, it's dynamically determining "yesterday" in the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DECLARE @yesterday SMALLDATETIME;
SET @yesterday = DATEADD(DAY,-1,CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())));

SELECT ...
WHERE X.stage = 'Approval'
AND X.T_ExitTime >= DATEADD(HOUR, 6, @yesterday)
AND X.T_ExitTime < DATEADD(HOUR, 17, @yesterday)
ORDER BY x.T_ExitTime;
```

Don't think you want `BETWEEN` for datetime ranges, unless you really want to include 5:00 PM and not 5:00:00.0000001 PM.

- [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)
- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Comment: Thanks a lot this is what I was looking for.... I think I can manage with this....Thanks again